# Google Play show different trending position from app page and common trending list

Tags: google-play, google-trends

On my app page in Google Play hanging badge "Trending #6", but in common list of trending apps it placed on 227th. What the difference between these places?

Answer (score 0):

On the app page trending takes into account app category filter